# Achieving Lipstick Effect with Google Mediapipe Face Mesh in AR Makeup Application

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, mediapipe

I am developing an AR makeup application using Google Mediapipe's face mesh. I am facing issues with texture coordinates around the lips and teeth, which makes it difficult to create a realistic lipstick effect. The lip area appears to spill onto the teeth in many cases. Can anyone share their experience or suggestions on how to successfully implement a lipstick effect using Mediapipe's face mesh?

Comment: Please provide a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: does this image help you?
https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/blob/master/face-landmarks-detection/mesh_map.jpg